# SharePoint User Profile Creation Oddity

Tags: user-profile

I have a couple farms setup with SharePoint 2010.

The dev farm is a single server with everything on it (except for the database), and another test farm has multiple web front ends and an app server (UPS is running on app server).

On the dev farm, if I add a new user to AD, login as that user into SharePoint, and navigate to the user's My Profile page (in My Sites), the user profile is created WITH all the attributes from AD pre-populated.

On the test farm, if I add a new user to AD, and login as that user into SharePoint, and navigate to the user's My Profile page (in My Sites), the user profile is created WITHOUT all the attributes from AD pre-populated. And I have to wait for the daily sync to run to get the properties populated.

I have tried to look at permissions and security throughout and can't figure out the difference between the two environments, except for the server architecture (WFE+APP, vs single server install). The app pool accounts in the test farm both have Administrator and Full permissions on the user profile application service.

Any ideas?

Comment: In order to get past this issue, we ended up writing some code to create and/or update the user profile directly if the profile had not yet synched from AD. It's not the optimal solution, as we would have preferred SP to do it for us. A fix for now, but would still be interested in a no-code solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have different UPS synch. schedules on the two farms?

You can initiate an incremental sync. on the test farm from Central Administration.

Writing custom code seems a drastic measure.

UPS seems to be much improved with SP1, with a newer FIM build - it might be worth investigating if this mitigates the issues.